# How can I reuse a test fragment in jmeter?

Tags: scope, include, jmeter

I have a JMeter test fragment which allows me to log into my application as a specific user. It looks something like this:

```
- Send a Login http request providing email and password
  - Extract a token from the response into a variable I can use later to make authenticated requests
```

This fragment gets the email and password to provide with the http request from user defined variables.

Using this fragment looks like this:

```
- Set User Defined Variables email and password
- Use the Include Controller to include the login fragment
- Expect the `token` variable to be set
```

This works wonderfully, but only once... Since the email and password are provided to the fragment as user defined variables, I thougth I could do something like this:

```
- Set email and password to `admin@example.com` and `admin123!`
- Use the Include Controller to include the login fragment (logging in as admin)
- Use `token` to make requests as that admin
- Set email and password to `anotherUser@example.com` and `superSecurePW`
- Use the Include Controller to include the login fragment (logging in as another user)
- Use `token` to make requests as that other user
```

However, since user defined variables are scoped to the Thread Group and don't seem to care about where they appear in the order of things, the second assignment overrides the first one, even for the first login request. In other words, both login requests are made with the same email and password, those for the *other* user.

How can I make this fragment reusable and parametrizable?

Comment: sorry, but I guess you gotta show the plan, especially how exactly you 'Set email and password to ...', and how you use them. and the reused fragment too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables):

1. All the **UDV** elements in a test plan are processed at the start of execution.
2. **UDV**s are processed in the order they appear in the **Test Plan**, from top to bottom.

So if you add several **UDV** elements which contain variables with identical names the latter variables will override the former ones.

If you want to change the variables before calling **Test Fragment** the second time you can add **JSR223 Sampler** with these two lines of code (don't forget to select Groovy as a language if you use an older JMeter version):

```
vars.put("email","anotherUser@example.com")
vars.put("password","superSecurePW")
```

Now your variables will have updated values.

Answer (score 1):

Try also the `Parameterized Controller`, to pass different values to your `Test Fragment` element (called possibly more times: from more controllers, and more threads; still defined just once), to call the same chunk of a reusable "code" with different values: No matter, whether these values are just constants (i.e. from a CSV file), or generated and further manipulated values from run-time flow.

Answer (score 0):

Within your ThreadGroup, you should add a 'CSV Data Set Config'.  This will allow you to specify your input in an external file that JMeter can then iterate on.  Once you do that, you can use those parameters/variables in your Test Fragment.  Enter the number of entries in your CSV Data Set file as the number of times to loop (set this on the ThreadGroup node).

This should give you your desired results.